# Handling rectangle coordinates in a 2D space

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11, matrix, coordinates

I would like to know if there's such a very basic method to know where exactly the translated object is in 2D space. I would like to clarify my thoughts regarding OpenGL matrices.

Please have a time to take a look at this very few code examples:

```
class Rectangle
{
public:

    //this function does amazing magic!
    //..so continue reading
    void draw();

    inline bool contains(int x, int y) const {
        return  x >= this->x && x <= this->x + width &&
                y >= this->y && y <= this->y + height;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
protected:

    std::vector<Rectangle *> children;
}
```

### solution #1

```
void Rectangle::draw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        ...
    //popped out the previous matrix so I have a fresh one
    glPopMatrix();

    //outside the matrix of parent
    //not logical (?)
    for (auto &i : children)
    {
        i->draw();
    }
}
```

### solution #2

```
void Rectangle::draw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        ...
        //inside the matrix of parent
        //good! the origin now is parent's coordinate.
        for (auto &i : children)
        {
            //previous matrix is not popped out so the origin is parent's (x,y)
            i->draw();
        }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

In **solution #1**, it is simple and very easy to locate the coordinates of each `Rectangle::children`, however, its quite hard to manage the code and its not an obvious choice for me because those `Rectangle::children`'s origin position must be their parent container, right?

On the other hand, I much preferred the **solution #2** and it is an obvious choice because, for every children I will create, their origin will be the parent's location. But, it's very hard for me to manage those `Rectangle::children`'s coordinates. For example, I want to have a `hover effect` applied on certain `Rectangle::children`, I would do in *implementation #1* as simple as this:

- *solution #1*

  ```
  for (auto &i : children)
  {
      if (i->contains(mouse().x, mouse().y)
      {
          //hover effect!
      }
  }
  ```
- *solution #2*

  ```
  for (auto &i : children)
  {
      if (i->contains(mouse().x - this->x, 
                      mouse().y - this->y)
      {
          //hover effect!
      }
  }
  ```

The main problem I'm really concern of is that I want to have a fixed function in the `Rectangle` class like `isHovering()` this will accept **0 number of parameters** and I want it be a `cv-qualified`. What this will do is: will check that the mouse cursor is inside the rectangle.

I think I would mess up the code for this function if I implement the solution #2 here. What do you think? Is there any nice way algorithm existing there I didn't know yet? I would like to ask first before I proceed along way.

Or...there's an `existing magic way` to implement in the drawing function to be able to achieve this?

Thanks for reading!

**Update**

Suppose the drawing hierarchy I want to achieve is something like this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

    //one matrix for every parent-rectangle and its child-rectangle component
    xPushMatrix();

        //parent
        glTranslatef(parent.x, parent.y, 0);
        glDrawables();

        //children
        glTranslatef(child.x, child.y, 0);
        glDrawables();
        ...to N child

    xPopMatrix();


xSwapBuffers(window);
xPollEvents();
```

The problem: **What is the right(efficient, clean code) way to find the coordinates of `Rectangle::children` ?**

Hope you get what I mean.

Comment: I cannot, for the life of me, understand you. Why would `#1` require arguments to be passed in, and not `#2`? P.S 
I'd really consider removing fixed pipeline calls, if it's an option.

Comment: @iccthedral `#1` and `#2` are the same except for code inside of it ?

Comment: @mr5: Actually, it is not clear to me what you are really asking for. You desging your scene as a classical scene graph hierarchy. In doing so, you will need the complete transformation path from the root to determine the local transformation at each node. In your case, there are only (2D) transformations, so you don't need a full-blown matrix, but can accumulate this in a simple (2D) vector.

Comment: @derhass I didn't understand. I will try to explain further what I really mean and want to achieve.

Comment: Btw: Don't use the fixed function pipeline anymore!

Comment: @FelixK. Can you suggest the simplest and efficient alternative way to `glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix()` ??

Comment: @mr5: in your case, it boild down to adding and copying 2D vectors.

Comment: @derhass What do you mean by copying of 2D vectors? Can you elaborate more? Also, please see my updated post. Thanks!

Comment: @mr5: Actually, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with your updated version. Do you really want to define each child relative to the previous child? Another things that you don't seem to understand how the GL matrix stack and transformations actually work.

Comment: @derhass Please disregard everything you see in my post. I failed at explaining my goal. So, how can I make, that all children are relative to its parent and easily locate the children's coordinates?

Comment: @mr5: Well. You seem to waht to define each rectangle's location relative to the parent's location. So, your solution #2 is the way to go, in principle. The location of each rectangle is well defined by the _accumulation_ of the parent and child translations. You can of course pre-calculate the complete accumulated local transformation per rectangle and store this in your object, so that you do not need to refer to any other rectangle when needing to know the position. You then have to recalculate this position for any moving rectangle, all its children and their children and so on.

Comment: @derhass Isn't it too ugly to design something like it that I need to track the previous children transformation, sum it up and subtract it to the mouse coordinates? That would be too messy I think?

Comment: @mr5: I don't really see the problem you have with this. You are **defining** the location of your rectanlge relative to the parent. If so, you need to take the parent's location into account when determining the position of your rectangle. There is no way around that.